# R: Using mice() to Impute Character/Factor Data w/ Lots of Possible Values

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, cardinality

I have a data set with six variables and about 5000 observations (rows). The variables are:

```
year, day_of_week, age, gender, race, state
```

Variables `year` and `age` are integers; the rest are factors. This data has some missing values. To replace them, I'm using mice as follows:

```
  impData <- mice(obs_subset, m = 3)
```

The call to mice() begins processing and outputting status until it reaches the `state` variable, then this:

```
Error in augment(y, ry, x, wy) : 
  Maximum number of categories (50) exceeded
```

Based on my research, it looks as though there are too many possible values for the `state` variable for the mice function to accommodate. Sure enough, there are 51 possible values (50 states and PR). If I exclude `state`, mice() runs fine.

My question is: how do I impute character data with high cardinality? Variables with low cardinality such as Male/Female/NB or Mon/Tue/Wed are easier. So what's the strategy for imputing when the number of possible value goes up, maybe way up? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try different imputation methods for `state`? I guess the default for categorical data with more than two values is `polyreg`. Maybe random forest (`rf`) or classification trees (`cart`) will work? They are time-consuming, though.